# Как продублировать Билд в Webpack?

Tags: webpack, webpack4

Сейчас работаю с темой для Wordpress и мне нужно чтобы папка диск компилировалась и дублировалась в тему где находиться Wordpress

```
let conf = {
    entry: './src/js/main.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/'),
        filename: "js/main.js",
        publicPath: ""
    },
```

Например чтобы он собирал и Dist и еще компилировал в ../themes/

что то типо такого

```
let conf = {
    entry: './src/js/main.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../themes/themeName'),
        filename: "js/main.js",
        publicPath: ""
    },
```